# Ubuntu selects my printer but nothing ever prints - Ubuntu 16.04 and HP DeskJet 3755

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, hp

**EDIT:** I got the printer to work using [THIS GUIDE](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html).

(Original Post is as follows)

So I was able to get Ubuntu to recognize my printer and be able to select it on my printers menu. But even with it selected and enabled, no print jobs go to it.

Let me know if additional details are needed to troubleshoot my problem.

Comment: Did you install HPLIP?

Comment: @George Yes, at least is should be. I worked on installing it yesterday but was still having issues with no printing.

Comment: @George Just checked with "dpkg -l hplip" and I have version 3.16.3+repac